# Typecasting the return type of iterator.next() method to Character class

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to display the contents of the following HashMap :

```
 HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
```

I have used the following method to print out the contents :

```
Set hmset = hm.entrySet();
Iterator iterator = hmset.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
    Character key = new Character(iterator.next());
    System.out.println("key : "+key+"value : "+(Integer)hm.get(key));
}
```

I am getting the following error :

```
error: constructor Character in class Character cannot be applied to given types;
```

I have also tried the following way of type casting :

```
Character key = (Character)iterator.next();
```

but that would'nt work either. Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parametrize your `Iterator` and use `keySet`:

```
Iterator<Character> iterator = hm.keySet().iterator();
```

**Explanation**

- Iterator is a generic type and should be parametrized. This way, you invoke `next` without having to cast from `Object` to your desired type.
- Invoking `entrySet` will return a `Set<Entry<Character, Integer>>`, which complicates your life unnecessarily if you're iterating the keys

Answer (score 0):

From `hm.entrySet()` you are trying to get `Set<Character,Integer>` not `Set<Character>`

It's better to use `keySet()`. Because it will return `Set<K>` (Here Key is Character. So will return `Set<Character>`):

```
Set hmset = hm.keySet();
    Iterator<Character> iterator = hmset.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
        Character key = new Character(iterator.next());
        System.out.println("key : "+key+"value : "+(Integer)hm.get(key));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
  Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            Character key = (Character)entry.getKey();
            Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
         System.out.println("key : "+key+"value : "+(Integer)hm.get(key));
        }
```

And why are you getting error in this line                                         `Character key = new Character(iterator.next());`?   . You are passing int value into Character Wrapper Class constructor. It will not allow this.

All the wrapper classes have constructors which can be used to create the corresponding Wrapper class objects by passing either a String or a variable of the same data type as that of the type to which the wrapper class corresponds, except for the Character wrapper class whose object cannot be created with a String.